# Change the names of pictures in a folder using a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, rename

I have several pictures of my students in a folder, and a list with their names in a text file.
I would like to creat a batch file to rename the pictures using the text file (names.txt) so that every picture has the name of the student.

All the pictures are in .png format. I searched this site and tried the following code :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem Load the list of new filenames
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (names.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "newname[!i!]=%%a"
)
rem Do the rename:
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o:n *.png') do (
   set /A i+=1
   for %%i in (!i!) do ren "%%a" "!newname[%%i]!"
)
```

I creat the batch file in the folder and when I execute it, there is nothing happening.
I think it is not picking the right folder to work into, but I'm not sure.

Example of files:

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
```

Example of `names.txt`

```
1_john_dalton
2_carol_denvers
3_steve_austin
```

Comment: You have a lot of for loops trying to achieve something not so complicated... but where are the examples of the actual filenames and the example of the content of `names.txt`?

Comment: The pictures are named 1 through 25. And the file names.txt has the names in a single column : 
1_john_dalton
2_carol_denvers
3_steve_austin
...

Comment: So did you manage yet?

Comment: Sadly it is not working.
I guess i'll just do it the old fashioned way.
Thanks a lot for the time you spent helping me !!

Comment: Not working? That is a really broad statement.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments and the construction of the current code, it seems you want something like this:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in (names.txt) do (
   for /f %%i in ('dir /b /o:n *.png') do echo ren "%%i" "%%a%%~xi"
)
```

This above will simply echo the result and not do the rename, only if you are happy with the results, can you remove `echo` from the last line, before ren.

Your example seems to want to resuse the old numeric name as well, so if indeed the case, then this should be it:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in (names.txt) do (
   for /f %%i in ('dir /b /o:n *.png') do echo ren "%%i" "%%a[%%~ni]%%~xi"
)
```